# How to access to website that hosted in web server inside laptop via mobile with out internet?

Tags: webserver

I try to browse my website that hosted in iis webserver in my laptop via mobile device with out internet.

Is this possible?
How to do that?

Comment: Do you have a router (even without Internet)? Do both devices have Bluetooth?

Comment: I have a router that laptop and mobile connected to the router wifi

Comment: Check if your router doesn't have a separation mode that disallows internal connections.